# (How) can I log messages with another severity than "log" in Elm?

Tags: logging, elm

I know about [`Debug.log`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Debug#log) - which logs a message with `log`-severity - and [`Debug.crash`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Debug#crash) - which crashes the application and logs a message with `error`-severity, but is there a way to log something with `error`, `warning`, or `info` severity without crashing the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no other built-in logging in Elm.  If you're just wanting to log to the console, you can use a port, or you can [write a native module](https://github.com/eeue56/take-home/wiki/Writing-your-first-Elm-Native-module) to call the `warn` and `error` methods directly.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [elm-logger](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/iosphere/elm-logger/latest) a while back.
[image]